I'd like to use roslibjs with TypeScript types to align with the Angular front-end. Is this feasible?
I found this repo containing type definitions and want to know if this is all I'll need for ensuring compatibility with Angular. Does anybody here have experience with using robot web tools with TypeScript?
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/roslib

Does Angular require types?

Yes, Angular is built on TypeScript and requires type definitions. I'm hoping that the repo I linked is enough to bridge the gap between roslib and Angular without having to go in and edit the common JS to reflect typing.

Are you sure you can't tell Angular to relax a little about types? Normally in typescript you can allow implicit "any", and also just allow JavaScript. Does Angular use a tsconfig.json?

It does use a tsconfig.json file, and one is included in that repo as well. Do you think changing the noImplicitAny value to true would take care of that?

it should! I would also set "allowJs": true.

Sweet, thank you! That's awesome.

Just recording the resolution here from the comments.
Update your tsconfig.json and set:
"allowJs": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,

